# How to add Cart Label

Tags: magento2

I know any label can be changed from i18n/en_US.csv.

But how to change as bellow picture

[image]

Could you please help for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the My Cart text on the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

Copy this file to your theme like:

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

And update it according to your requirement. Also if you want the text on the next line then manage it through css.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If its working upvote please.